# How can I solve the error 'Array dimensions exceeded supported range' during Machine Learning

Tags: ml.net

Im am using ML.Net Model Builder to Load and Train a dataset. During training about 20 models are used to train. On a couple of models (LbfgsMaximumEntropyMulti, FastForestOva)  I get the error 'Array dimensions exceeded supported range'. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Kind regards

Comment: Not too sure but I'd try targetting x64 and setting [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element) and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Thanks Peter, I give it a try.
Because it is a .Net Core 3.1 project, I added this as a environment variable: COMPlus_gcAllowVeryLargeObjects=1

Comment: What data are you using?

Comment: Setting gcAllowVeryLargeObjects made no difference, and in fact I believe the issue comes from Model Builder: during training of the data the errors occurs.

Comment: @Jon: Model Builder has to train about 155.000 records. Each records does have integer and string data. I am using the scenario 'Multi class classification'

Comment: @Balu Can you show a sample of the data that you're using?

Comment: Scenario 1. If I use model (onnx created with customvision.ai) the project reports this error.
Scenario 2. If I use model inside .NET 6 target DLL, it compiles fine. The moment I reference this Project/dll inside another .NET 6 target UWP/WinUI3 project I get this error in the UI app code.

So apparently/probably it is not the array size issue but the reference to one or all of Microsoft.ML and its dependencies is. Any help is appreciated.